# Deleting std::thread pointer raises exception "libc++abi.dylib: terminating"

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, stdthread

In C++ 11 with LLVM 6.0 on Mac OS X, I first created a pointer to a memory allocation of std::thread.

```
std::thread* th = new std::thread([&] (int tid) {
    // do nothing.
}, 0);
```

Then I tried to delete it.

```
delete th;
```

However, compiling the above code and execute it raises exception

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating
Abort trap: 6
```

Comment: Did you join it or detach it? Any why the dynamic allocation?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The thread you've created is [`joinable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/joinable), and unless you [`join`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join) or [`detach`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/detach) it, `std::terminate` will be called when the [destructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/~thread) of the thread object executes. So you need

```
th->join();
delete th;
```

---

Early proposals for `std::thread` implicitly `detach`ed the thread in the destructor, but this was found to cause problems when the owning thread threw an exception between creation and `join`ing of a `thread` instance. [N2802](http://www.open-std.org/Jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2802.html) contains the change proposal along with illustrative examples.

The original behavior was carried over from `boost::thread` but it too has since [deprecated](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.thread.destructor) implicit `detach` in the destructor.

---

Unrelated to your problem, but it is very unlikely you need to dynamically allocate the thread object, and even if you do, you should be storing it in a `unique_ptr`.

Comment: I dynamically allocate the threads in order to push them in std::vector, since std::thread does not have copy constructor.

Comment: Why by design we need to call thread->detach(), instead of the destructor of thread objects does that for us?

Comment: @Strin It doesn't need to be copyable. `std::vector` can handle move only types, and `std::thread` is moveable. As for requiring that the user call `join` or `detach`, IIRC the original `std::thread` proposal's destructor did do just that, but it was discovered to be problematic. Let me try and dig up why the change was made.

Comment: You can also have a look at the emplace to construct the object inplace in the vector.