# Visual Studio 2013 std::thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, visual-studio-2013, stdthread

the following program give some strange compile/run-time behavior when compiled with Visual Studio 2013:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{

    {//works
        std::thread([](){
            std::cout << " thread running1\n";
        });
    }

    {//compile but synstax error exist
        auto func = [](){
            std::cout << " thread running2\n";
        };

        std::thread(fun); //fun is not defined
    }


    {//compile, see next block for mystery compile error
        auto func = [](){
            std::cout << " thread running2\n";
        };

        std::thread tmp(func); 
    }

    {//does not compile and don't know why
        auto func = [](){
            std::cout << " thread running2\n";
        };

        std::thread(func); //error C2371: 'func' : redefinition; different basic types
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When this program work, there may crash as there is race condition between the thread. The main thread may end before the other threads.

Does anybody know why the second block and last block does not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{//compile but synstax error exist
    auto func = [](){
        std::cout << " thread running2\n";
    };

    std::thread(fun); //fun is not defined
}
```

There's no syntax error here, `std::thread(fun)` default constructs an `std::thread` object named `fun`.

The error in the last block is because of the same reason

```
std::thread(func); //error C2371: 'func' : redefinition; different basic types
```

You're trying to default construct an `std::thread` object named `func` above and that's an error because a lambda of the same name already exists in the same scope. To pass the lambda to the `thread` constructor use braces instead

```
 std::thread{func};
```

---

Now, after you've made these changes your code will compile but will fail at runtime because the thread objects in blocks 1, 3 & 4 are all going to call `std::terminate` (of course, your program terminates when the first thread object calls `std::terminate` so the other two doing that is a moot point).

The reason that happens is that you have *joinable* threads in all 3 blocks and if the [destructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/~thread) of such a thread object runs, [`std::terminate` will be called](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25397925/241631). To avoid that you must call `thread::join` (you could also call `thread::detach` but don't do that).

For instance

```
{//works
    std::thread([](){
        std::cout << " thread running1\n";
    }).join();
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0798261a110ac44e)

Comment: Where did the syntax changed in c++? My understanding was that std::thread(func); will create an unnamed object passing func to the constructor. Ps my program works now :-)

Comment: @Johan It's always been this way. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6342009/241631); you can add even more pairs of parentheses if you like :)